# How to sort version number in Angular 2 custom pipe?

Tags: angular, sorting, angular2-custom-pipes

Angular 4 - how to sort version number string in an array using custom pipe?

I have a json file with version number like v.9.1, v.9.2, v10.0. I tried sorting using custom pipe but sorted as v.9.2, v.9.1, v.10.0 rather than v.10.0, v.9.2, v.9.1. So it looks like it's been treated as string.

Here is what I have tried in the pipe:

```
import {Injectable, PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import { P11dComponent } from './p11d.component';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sortByVersion'
})

@Injectable()
export class SortVersionPipe implements PipeTransform{

transform(array: Array<any>, args: string): Array<any> {
        if (array !== undefined) {

            array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                if ( parseFloat(a[args.slice(3,4)]) < parseFloat(b[args.slice(3.4)]) ){
                    return 1;
                } else if ( parseFloat(a[args.slice(3,4)]) < parseFloat(b[args.slice(3.4)]) ) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;   
                }
            });
        }
        return array;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have array like:

```typescript
arr = ['v.9.1', 'v.9.2', 'v.10.0']
```

then `transform` method could look like:

```typescript
transform(array: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    if(!array) {
      return null;
    }
    return array.sort((a, b) => b.slice(2) - a.slice(2));
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3GY21tycts8VuxFgLOZk?p=preview)**

Just a note: you do not need to use `@Injectable` for classes that has already adorned `@Component`, `@NgModule`, `@Directive` or `@Pipe` decorator.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work in my code. I am extracting data from a json file which is like this -

Comment: @farialmahmud I added json file to my example https://plnkr.co/edit/zqpkih1AaRAgySyklOrZ?p=preview Can you reproduce it there?

Comment: [
  {
    "version" : "v.9.1",
    "date" : "08/11/2016",
    "link": "9-1/setup.zip"
  },
    {
    "version" : "v.9.0",
    "date" : "05/08/2016",
    "link": "9-0/setup.zip"
  },
  {
    "version" : "v8.1",
    "date" : "02/11/2015",
    "link": "8-1/setup.zip"
  },
  
   {
    "version" : "v9.2",
    "date" : "20/03/2017",
    "link": "9-2/setup.zip"
  },
   {
    "version" : "v10.0",
    "date" : "20/03/2017",
    "link": "10.0/setup.zip"
  }
]

Comment: I am getting this data in a component through an Interface -

export interface iSometLinks {
    version:string;
    date: Date;
    link: string;
}

Used ngFor to view this like below

<tr *ngFor="let someLink of someLinks | sortByVersion: 'version'">
                        <td>{{someLink.version}}</td>

Comment: i also needed to sort version numbers like v4.0.0.10, v4.0.0.15, v4.0.0.40 etc. which i sorted like below. Posting as someone may find it useful.

export class SortVerPipe implements PipeTransform{
 
transform(array: Array<any>, args: string): Array<any> {
    if (array !== undefined) {
        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if ( a.version < b.version ){
                return 1;
            } else if ( a.version > b.verision ) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;   
            }
        });
    }
    return array;
}
}